# how to login to mybb forum from an intel xdk application

Tags: javascript, php, intel-xdk, mybb

for christmas i'm developing an intel-xdk app to send to all the users of my mybb forum.
The app need to authenticate the user, only registered forum users can login into.

a first way i thought is to add a php function into the website and call through ajax passing username & password. In this case i know how to implements.

just for learning i would like to know if there is a way to use all the existing server code.

can one intel-xdk authenticate one user over mybb forum? if yes what's the way?

Comment: If you are asking "can I embed PHP code in my HTML files when using the XDK?" -- the answer is no. The pages your app is executing are not being served up or processed by a server, they are strictly client-side pages that are stored on the client and are not associated with a web server or domain.

Comment: no, i'm not asking to embed php code, i just want to authenticate a user from hybrid app against mybb database (mysql hosted in altervista.org).